# Laravel API isn't getting inputs

Tags: php, rest, laravel-5, postman

I am developing a `REST` `API` in `laravel` and upon requesting it I am posting some data. But in `laravel` controller nothing appears. This is my controller code:

```
try {
      $rules = [
         'type' => 'required|integer'
      ];

      $validator = Validator::make($this->inputs, $rules);
      if ($validator->passes()) {
         //code here
      } else {
         return response()->json([
                'status' => $this->BAD_REQUEST,
                    'response' => [
                        'message' => $validator->messages(),
                        'data' => $this->NO_DATA_ARRAY
                    ],
                ], $this->BAD_REQUEST);
      }
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => $this->BAD_REQUEST,
                'response' => [
                    'message' => $ex->getMessage(),
                    'data' => $this->NO_DATA_ARRAY
                ],
            ], $this->BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Now when I do `print_r($this->inputs);` I get nothing. I am sending the request from `postman` and sending the data as `form-data`. I have tried sending it using an online API tester as well. Still the same result. Any help?

Comment: use laravel `Request` object for that

Comment: try sending data as x-www-form-urlencoded from postman. If externally you are not defining the request type then 'x-www-form-urlencoded' is default.

Comment: @Naincy I have tried that as well with the same result

Comment: you will be getting data in Request object in Laravel not in $this->inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests)
Include the following use statement on top of the class below namespace.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

A sample function in controller will look like

```
     /**
     * Sample controller function
     * @param  Request  $request
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
      // get request method 
      $method = $request->method();

     // retrieve all input as array
     $input = $request->all();
    }
```